# Proper iptables rules to allow Guests network connection

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM running on Ubuntu 14.04 with a few guests (mostly CentOS7) behind NAT configuration.

It seems the guests can't reach the internet connection if the following firewall rules are activated in the host server :

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p all -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT iptables -A INPUT -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT iptables -A INPUT -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT
```

The last four lines are part of my attempts I have been trying.. no luck!!

If the firewall is disabled, everything works fine. Can you please advice what rules/configuration should I include into my script?

Answer (score 1):

after several attempts on my own I found the solution to fix the issue just by adding the following rule into my script :

iptables -A INPUT -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT

notice : virbr1 is my local KVM nat network used by the VMs.

so, the script now looks like below :

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --source 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i virbr1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p all -j DROP
```

very important to have the DROP rule as last line .. this is my understanding so far, but someone here may want to give us more details ..